# Moving average for multiple stock in python

Tags: python, moving-average

I have been calculating the simple moving average of a stock using the code below:

```py
def SMA(data, period =30, column='Close'):
    return data[column].rolling(window=period).mean()

df['SMA20']=SMA(df,20)
df['SMA50']=SMA(df,50)
```

**How do I calculate the moving average for various stocks that are apart of the same data set?**
*If I apply the above code then the moving average for the **second** or **third** stock in the row will be incorrect.*

Comment: Can you write the sample expected output & what you are getting with the above code snippet

Comment: Also an example of the data would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, if this works for you

```
df = (
    df.fillna(0).groupby(["ticker_exchange"])[["price"]]
    .rolling(30)
    .corr().iloc[0::2,-1]
)
```